# Printing the error message without the [ ]

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

Ok so It's more like if there is an easy way to the output to

```
[6, 8, 9, 10]
[1002]
empty array []
Bad input
Bad input
Bad input
Bad input
```

If that is the case how?

It's more like nitpicking on something mostly irreverent and before I start doing something that is gonna take a lot of time just to have the output be ''nicer''

So I just wanna simply know if it can be done in an easy way and if that is the case how.

```
public class String2intArray {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("6,8 ,9 , 10")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("1002")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia(", 2")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("Ett,Två")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((str2ia("1,,2"))));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("1 , 2 ,")));
  }

  public static int[] str2ia(String s) {
    int arraylengt = 0;
    int arrayindex = 0;
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(",");
    if(s.length() == 0) {
        int[] emptyArray = {};
        System.out.print("empty array ");
        return emptyArray;
    }
    try {
      if(!s.matches("(\\d+,)*\\d+")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input");            
      }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.print("Bad input");
        int[] emptyArray = {};
        return emptyArray;
    }
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int nextInt = scan.nextInt();

            arraylengt ++;
        } else {
            // discard next token
            scan.next();
        }
      }

      int[] intArray = new int[arraylengt];

      Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(",");
      try {
        while (scan2.hasNext()) {
            if (scan2.hasNextInt()) {
                intArray[arrayindex] = scan2.nextInt();
                arrayindex++;

            } else {
                // discard next token
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input");
            }        
          }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.print("Bad input");
            int[] emptyArray = {};
            return emptyArray;

        }           
    return intArray;            
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to control the output, then you won't be using `Arrays.toString`. Write your own.

Comment: you can do it in many ways: for example you can create a print method who clear the array as you wish, or you can create a class that extends array and override toString()

Comment: Define your own formatter.

Comment: The easiest way is `IntStream.of(array).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve the required output by making *2 changes* to the existing code:

**First:** Replace the following code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("6,8 ,9 , 10")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("1002")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia(", 2")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("Ett,Två")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((str2ia("1,,2"))));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("1 , 2 ,")));
```

*-with-*

```
// Define the input as an array of input strings and print result
// by iterating the input array elements
String [] inputStrings = {"6,8 ,9 , 10", "1002", "", ", 2", "Ett,Två", "1,,2", "1 , 2 ,"};
for (String input : inputStrings) {
    int [] result = str2ia(input);
    if (result == null) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

*-AND-*

**Second**: Replace the following code:

```
...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.print("Bad input");
    int[] emptyArray = {};
    return emptyArray;
}
```

*-with-*

```
...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.print("Bad input");
    // Return null instead of an empty array, in case of bad input.
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create your own code to iterate over the array:

```
int[] aArray = str2ia("6,8 ,9 , 10");
for (int number : aArray) {
  System.out.print(number);
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: That code will mash all of the values together. For example, if the array contains 10, 2, 35, and 617 it will write "10235617". Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @FredK Well it kinda is, I just wanted to know if there was an easy way to do it, and from the comments I have received I have decided that spending probably hours (yes I am this bad at programming) just so I can change a single thing of the output. That is nothing more than an error message incase the something is wrong with the input.